# Int To Pimage error

Tags: java

Im trying to make filter for my Java document.

This is my code but it dosen't work. Dont mind the m4 == 1, ak == 1, and awp == 1.

```
PImage weapon1;
PImage weapon2;
PImage weapon3;
PImage billed;
int weapon;
int m4 = 0;
int ak = 0;
int awp = 1;
void setup() {
  weapon1 = loadImage("dayz.jpg");
  weapon2 = loadImage("ak47.jpg");
  weapon3 = loadImage("295020.jpg");
  billed = loadImage("dayz.jpg");
```

Its the int weapon that does the error but i need the int weapon to get my code working like i want.

```
void pixel2(){
  if(m4 == 1){
  weapon = weapon1;
  }
  else if(ak == 1){
  weapon = weapon2;
  }
  else if(awp == 1){
  weapon = weapon3;
  }
  for(int y = 0; y < weapon.height; y = y+3){
    for(int x = 0; x < weapon.width; x = x+3){
      color pilex1 = weapon.get(x, y);
      strokeWeight(1);
      stroke(1);
      fill(pilex1);
      rect(x,y,3,3);
    }
  }
  }
```

The Answer:

```
if(m4 == 1){ 
weapon = loadImage("295020.jpg"); } 
else if(ak == 1){ 
weapon = loadImage("ak47.jpg"); } 
else if(awp == 1){ 
weapon = loadImage("dayz.jpg"); }
```

Comment: `Its the int weapon that does the error` - this is a question?

Comment: yo cant assign a PImage to int variable

Comment: Why isn't `weapon` a `PImage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int weapon;` should be `PImage weapon;`.
`PImage billed;` isn't being used by the way.

Comment: Found a new way, with you inspiration,   if(m4 == 1){
    weapon = loadImage("295020.jpg");
  }
  else if(ak == 1){
    weapon = loadImage("ak47.jpg");
  }
  else if(awp == 1){
    weapon = loadImage("dayz.jpg");
  }